# Work item access for non visual-studio users

Tags: tfs

We're using TFS for source control and are trialling using the TFS work item tracking. I am trying to find out, is it possible for people who don't have visual studio installed to access, create and edit work items via a browser based user interface?

Our technical support team need to be able to use work items. TFS work items won't be suitable for our company if the support team and project managers can't get sufficient access.

I'm not familiar with how the licensing works either. If there is a way for non visual studio users to use TFS work items, will they need a license?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The are a number of choices (most costing money):

1. **[Team System Web Access](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/teamsystem/bb676728.aspx)**
   Team System Web Access (formerly known as TeamPlain) is a Web interface to Visual Studio 2005 Team Foundation Server. Team System Web Access is available as a free download for existing Team Foundation Server users, and will be incorporated into a future release of Visual Studio Team System.
2. **[Work Item Only View](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668124.aspx)**
   Team System Web Access provides a work item only view that restricts functionality so that you can create and view only your own work items. This view is designed to facilitate working with Team Foundation Server when you do not have a client access license (CAL). You do not need a CAL to create new work items or to view and update work items that you created. The work item only view restricts functionality so that you are in compliance with this aspect of the Team Foundation Server end user license agreement. For more information, see [Visual Studio Team System 2008 Licensing White Paper](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=CE194742-A6E8-4126-AA30-5C4E969AF2A3&displaylang=en).
3. **[Outlook integration](http://blogs.msdn.com/bharry/archive/2009/03/17/tfs-outlook-add-ins.aspx)** (from Brian Harry's blog)
   Integration of Team Foundation Server work items into the Outlook user experience continues to be a popular area for innovation.  Just recently an author sent me mail about a new one called Wit-It! that enables work item forms to be easily opened from TFS work item change notifications.  It's not entirely unlike configuring links to Team System Web Access from event notifications but it uses local rich client UI that some will like better.

   There are several other Outlook extension offerings out there with varying levels of completeness.  If it's an area that iterests you, you can also check out:

   [TeamExpand](http://www.teamexpand.com/)

   [TeamLook](http://www.personifydesign.com/products/teamlook/teamlook.aspx)

   [TeamCompanion](http://www.ekobit.com/ProductsDetailView.aspx?id=1)

   And I appologize if I left any out.  As I say, clearly there is a lot of interest here and some creative people.

Answer (score 4):

[Team System Web Access](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/teamsystem/bb676728.aspx) is a good web-based option for non-visual studio users.

Comment: Hmm. I was getting confused between the project portal and the web access. I thought they were the same thing, but it doesn't look like they are. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There should be a web interface, both a website and a SharePoint portal that gets installed with TFS. The portal will let you get to the documents and view some reports. The website will let you work with the documents, the source control, work items, and bug reporting.

Answer (score 1):

As far as licensing goes, a full-blown TFS user requires a TFS CAL (in addition to the normal Windows Server CAL).

However, for particular types of 'light' users a TFS CAL might not be required (I'm not sure, but I'd think that a Windows Server CAL would still be required).  See http://blogs.msdn.com/bharry/archive/2007/11/23/tfs-licensing-change-for-tfs-2008.aspx for some details.

As always, MS server application licensing requirements are often quite complicated - you will need to do your own research (probably in consultation with MIcrosoft) to determine your actual licensing requirements.